# JaCoCo Vs Intellij Code coverage tool (If Else condition)

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, jacoco

I have a simple method with a unit test written in flat spec , in intellij when I try to run my test using JaCoCo as coverage tool the IF condition is partially covered where as same test code using Intellij code coverage tool it is 100% covered so does JaCoCo has any kind of problem ?

```
  def ifElse(novalue: String, platform: String) =
    if (novalue == "NoValue" && platform == "PLATFORM") {
      true
    } else {
      false
    }
```

Unit test code

```
  it should "ifElse True Test" in {
    ifElse("NoValue", "PLATFORM") should be(true)
    ifElse("blah", "blah") should be(false)
    ifElse("NoValue", "PLATFORM2") should be(false)
    ifElse("NoValue2", "PLATFORM") should be(false)
  }
```

Using Intellij Code Coverage Tool 100% covered if condition :-
[image]

Using JaCoCo Code Coverage Tool if condition is not getting covered :-
[image]

[image]

[image]

Thanks
Sri

Comment: Please create an issue at YouTrack sharing the sample project to reproduce the case: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA. Thank you